# ScrollViewer is not working inside FlipView

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have been working around to find out solution for scrolling inside `FlipView`, however, the scrolling is not working properly. I am using `SplitView` template in my page and I have put FlipView inside Frame.

```
<Frame>
<FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding QuranPages}" 
 SelectedItem="{Binding QuranPageSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
 Padding="20" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
   <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
           <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
               VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                   <Image  Stretch="UniformToFill"
                           Source="{Binding PageUri}" 
                   MaxWidth="{Binding DataContext.PageWidth,  ElementName=MyPage}"
                  MaxHeight="{Binding DataContext.PageHeight,  ElementName=MyPage}">
          </Image>
          </ScrollViewer>
  </DataTemplate>
 </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
 </FlipView>
</Frame>
```

In Page_SizeChanged event I am updating with page size with followings;

```
private void Page_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
   this.model.PageWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width; //e.NewSize.Width-10;
   this.model.PageHeight = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;     //e.NewSize.Height-10;
}
```

I don't understand why the scroll is not working properly, though it shows the scroll viewer, but it's not scrolling.

**Update 1**

I have noticed that it works well with other images, but it doesn't work with these images [Image 1](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DBBC281099F4FE69%21109726) [Image 2](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DBBC281099F4FE69%21109727) [Image 3](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DBBC281099F4FE69%21109728)

**Update 2**

Here I have also added the scrollviewer Image and you can see half image is appearing, the other half is not appearing while the scrollivewer is at end.
[image: ScrollViewer with Half Image]

My pictures are in PNG format, do I need to change their format?

**Update 3**

I have added the scrollviewer with Image. The scrollviewer seems Ok, but the image is not loaded properly.

[image: Image Sample with ScrollViewer]

Thanks!

Comment: According to your description and the code provided above, I have created a sample to test **scrolling inside FlipView**, and the scroll **works** all fine. Here is the [Entire Sample](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E754412D31A2DF3D!111&authkey=!AIv3qgqlJTtBPCc&ithint=file%2czip) and the [output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qvfgi.gif) for your reference.

Comment: @JerryLi Thanks, My codes also works well with your images. however, it doesn't work with images (see update link). I am afraid, why it should behave different with images?

Comment: You're welcome:) I have tried adding images provided above to my project, and it works fine too. Here is the [output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lpsvP.gif). So could you share your project which can reproduce this issue to us for further investigation?

Comment: Thanks, the scrollviewer in your example works, but if you see, only half the image is display not the full image. (if you don't mind, please open the image and check it with this scrollviewer, only half of the image is shown, not the full image)

Comment: You're welcome:) I noticed that too. And it is because the MaxWidth and MaxHeight of the image are bind to Window.Current.Bounds.Width/Height, so sometimes only half the image is displayed. If removing these two bindings,  full image will be shown. So why do you want to bind the MaxWidth and MaxHeight of the image to to Window.Current.Bounds.Width/Height? :)

Comment: Thanks, Well, I require that for zooming, but for time being I won't use that. Even though I removed With & Height from the Image, I couldn't get the result. Now the scroll is available correctly, but Image is not displayed correctly.

Comment: So you mean you still cannot get the full image?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated and uploaded the image after removing Width & Height from Image

Comment: You're welcome:) I was not able to reproduce the issue. Here is the [output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/24Grg.gif) I got, and the [sample code](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E754412D31A2DF3D!114&authkey=!ACIHTF7J8dyPKq4&ithint=file%2czip) I used for testing.